# How to make a WSGI app configurable by any server?

Tags: python, wsgi

Is there a way to distribute a WSGI application that will work out of the box with any server and that will be configurable using the server's built-in features only?
This means that the only configuration file the administrator would have to touch would be the server's configuration file. It wouldn't be necessary to write a custom WSGI script in Python.

mod_wsgi adds configuration variables set with `SetEnv` to the WSGI environ dictionary that gets passed to the app, but I didn't find a way to do something similar with Gunicorn or uWSGI. Using `os.environ` works with Gunicorn and uWSGI but not with mod_wsgi because `SetEnv` doesn't affect `os.environ`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `environ` and `os.environ` are mappings.

```
servername = environ.get('servername', os.environ.get('servername', 'localhost))
```

Comment: I know but it seems a bit hackish, doesn't it? Is it standard practice?

Comment: Standard practice is to write it to the WSGI container. You've decided that you don't want that.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to help an open source project that has made that decision. I can understand why: it would allow sysadmins to deploy the app without knowing any Python syntax.

Comment: Perhaps your efforts would be better spent towards getting everyone to use `environ` instead.

Comment: Yes as this seems to be the practice advertised by PEP 333: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#application-configuration I'm surprised that neither Gunicorn nor uWSGI seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

in uWSGI (if using the uwsgi protocol) you can pass additional variables with uwsgi_param key value in nginx, SetEnv in apache (both mod_uwsgi and mod_proxy_uwsgi), cgi vars with Cherokee and --http-var with the uwsgi http router.

For the http protocol (in gunicorn or uWSGI http-socket) the only solution popping in my mind is adding special headers in the proxy configuration that you will parse in your wsgi app (http headers are rewritten as cgi vars prefixed with HTTP_)